# UIView, NSMutableArray and addSubview deallocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

This question is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179251/custom-uitableviewcell-deallocated-when-added-to-array) of mine to which I couldn't get an answer, but I think I am getting closer.

I have a `UIView`, that is added to an `NSMutableArray`. Later I add that `UIView` as a subview of another view, **but without removing it from the array**. Does this mean that my `UIView` is no longer an item in my array?

In other words, does the `-addSubview` method automatically remove my `UIView` object from the `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. Your array and the superview to which you added the UIView will retain the view. That's all.

This can become a bit nasty if your UIView is unloaded due to a memory warning but is still in memory because of your array still retaining the instance.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I guess I am back to square one for the previous question though...

Comment: I just posted an answer to your other question.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. You have to explicitly remove it if you want it gone.

Answer (score 0):

No, it should still be inside the array.